# Best way to improve combat without paying for training?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I would like to increase my Warfare and Sword skill without having to pay anyone for training.

So far I have been doing the main quest (left Neuhof) and the miller quest and have encountered very little fighting. Every now and then there is a bandit in the woods but is usualy alone and really easy to take down.

Is there a place I can go spar like I did in the begining with capitan Bernard? Or is there an area where I can find lots of bandits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After Bernard returns from Neuhof to Rattay you can spar with him again. He should offer the dialogue options to spar or spar with real weapons. Both will give experience in the combat abilities.

Comment: thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. Don't have enough to upvote :/

Comment: His combo training is supposed to be the best bet, as it goes on forever if you do not do the combo he is looking for, does not ever damage you, and he does not parry every strike you make.

Comment: @Jonathon He doesn't attack you in the combo training though, meaning you don't get defence experience.

Comment: For advanced training, fast travel for long distances to encounter wayfaring knights to duel. This may or may not require you to wear knightly armour. They tend to be skilled and well equipped but will not kill you if they win, also you can bet on the duel.

Comment: @Pahlavan, adding to comment: You should look for knights, but avoid mercenaries. Because fight with mercenary would require you to bet some groshen, and knights fight for honor, unless you specifically force them to bet (knight-coward won't take anything even you force him to bet).

Comment: @Pahlavan That seems unreliable to me. In my 40 hours of gameplay so far, I've met a wayfaring knight once.

Comment: @Dulkan Interesting, I didn't know it was that random. I've never made it from Thalmberg to Rattay or vice versa without encountering one, sometimes two.

Answer (score 3):

Also, since the Tournament udpate, you can now enroll in the Rattay tourney every 5 days (approximately) by talking to the herald in the upper castle courtyard. But the registration fee is 60 groschens, but you can earn much more if you win the fights. Also, Miller Peshek makes bets on the tourney too.

If you own the From the Ashes DLC, you can also build (not for free though) a guard house somewhere (I won't spoil you where), which comes with a fighting area and a master-at-arms where you can train for free.